# Drupal override search form: how to debug hook failure?

Tags: hooks, theming, search

In the past I've always been able to override the theme form using the method mentioned http://drupal.org/node/154137.

```
function YOURTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
        $form['search_block_form']['#title'] = t('Search');
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't appear to be recognised in the template.php of my latest theme. It hasn't been an issue in the past - what is the best way to debug why the hook doesn't appear to be activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Clear cache.
- Place some debugging code to see if the hook and then if statement is called.
- Inspect the form variable, does it look correct?

Comment: No debugging output is there. I'm slightly at a loss. I've just moved the theme over to a fresh Drupal installation and the hooks aren't being picked up. The setup is identical between the two instances. Its very odd!

Comment: On extra debugging, found the issue which was elsewhere in the file and preventing it being correctly processed.